# FlashDevelop doesn't show compile errors after upgrade to Flash Pro CC

Tags: flashdevelop

I've been using FlashDevelop with Flash Pro CS6. It was able to show compile errors in the Results panel which is a huge time saver.

After upgrading to Flash Pro CC, I'm still able to test the project from FlashDevelop, but the compile errors don't show anymore. Suggestions?

Comment: This is a question for superuser.com

Comment: Perhaps, but a search for FlashDevelop on superuser.com returns 11 results while here it returns 1,753 results. Do you have a link to a document that supports your statement?

Comment: I apologise - the About page mentions questions related to "software development tools", which I guess makes this an on-topic question here. And I wouldn't be one to suggest that using a computer is different from programming it (and so the question is doubly relevant, ideally at least), but in this case we can all admit you can't do anything else but wait for another version of FlashDevelop. Unless you want to recompile it after patching in required functionality of course ;-)

Comment: Thank you for checking that. The last thing I would like to do is violate the rules here. I love StackOverflow :)

Comment: BTW, I would appreciate reversing the "-1".

Comment: It doesn't allow me to. I feel a bit dirty on the inside now.

Comment: Try to edit the question (just for the sake of it). It says I can undo my vote when the question is edited.

Comment: Done. But seriously, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash CC error report syntax has changed and FlashDevelop 4.4.2 doesn't recognize them.

This should be fixed in a future update of FlashDevelop.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how soon will that happen?

Comment: It's fixed in SVN already so it will be fine in the next release.

Comment: Great! Where can I go to find out when this fix will be available?